# Can the pricebook be changed when cloning an opportunity with product?

Tags: opportunity, pricebook, clone

I have a location field on Opportunity which is tied up with a pricebook. If I clone the Opportunity with products, it won't allow me to change the location because it's associated to that pricebook.
 Now how do I clone an Opp with products and change the location so that will set the pricebook to that corresponding location on the cloned Opp?

Highly appreciate any help.

Comment: so `Opportunity.pricebook2Id` is set by some trigger based on `Opportunity.location__c` ?  You may need to override the OOB Clone button to present a VF form wherein user can enter Location__c and then you do the heavy lifting of cloning OLI in the VF controller.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot clone an Opportunity with Products and also change the Price Book while keeping the Products because the OpportunityProducts aren't just OpportunityProducts - they also contain a reference to a Price Book Entry record. So the system cannot just change the Price Book because there is no system rule that enforces that the same "Products" (Price Book Entry - Product relationships) exist in every Price Book.

You will need to write a script to do a custom clone that will find the Price Book Entries in the new Price Book that correspond to the Opportunity Product Price Book Entries in the old one, and will then attach those to the Opportunity.

Quite complicated, as you can see! For more information, see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_products.htm.